# returning a set of string in java

Tags: java, string, recursion, set

First, I would like to apologize because of my bad English. Now, how do I return a set of string using recursion? I know the logic but I can't figure out how to return the set after adding all these words from a string.

example with a string like this

```
String s = "how do i return this?";
```

After passing this string into the method, I need to create a set, then using recursion to remove the string (which will be added to the set, and return the set).

When the set is returned, I supposed to output the set to a file.

My logic is:

```
//because every word in the string ends with a space
//So I need to get the index of that space
int n = s.indexOf(' ');
//add each word to the set (each word start at index 0 to the index of the space ' '.
set.add(s.substring(0, n));
//recursive case ( keep doing this until the length of string is 0.)
methodName(n+1, s.length());
```

I know I can do this with class variable (set), but I need to use local in this case and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: but in this situation i can only use charAt, length, indexOf, substring..no other methods allowed, also no loops.

Comment: ok! i made you an example without using split with recursive call

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But i got the problem solved.  I had all my code ready, and it's just that i didn't use addAll for the recursion. (i used add, and it gave me a bunch of errors).

Comment: you still can using `add` without `addAll` passing the set as Parameter i'll edit my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return anything from a method, you define your method like:

```
<return type> methodName(parameters) {
    // code
    return retval;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
<return type> retval = methodName(parameters);
```

So, define your method to return `Set<String>`, and replace the last line with this:

```
set.addAll(methodName(n+1, s.length()));
```

Finally, add a return statement:

```
return set;
```

You are done.

Comment: awesome. No wonder why it didn't work.. i used set.add(methodName(n+1, s.length()));    Basically i know everything else, it just that i didn't use addAll, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add set to parameter of method:

```
methodName(n+1, s.length(), set);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

My advice

- use LinkedHashSet as your Set implementation, so you'll get the tokens in the order they were inserted
- your recursive method must pass the Set as parameter (so it can accumulate your tokens)
- don't forget to add a way to stop the recursion inside your recursive method (for example, if your index goes after the end of the string)

My way of solving this has a method like

```
private static void recursiveMethod(String x, Set<String> s)
```

where x is a substring of the previous string.

Answer (score 0):

You need a base case to know where you finish recursion, actually using indexOf is a good choice if it's -1 then you don't have nothing to do.

Example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RecursionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
       methodName("how do i return this?", set);
       System.out.println(set);
   }

   static void methodName(String s, Set<String> set) {
    // because every word in the string ends with a space
    // So I need to get the index of that space
    int n = s.indexOf(' ');
    // base case
    if (n < 0) {
        set.add(s);
        return;
    }
    // add each word to the set (each word start at index 0 to the index of
    // the space ' '.
    set.add(s.substring(0, n));
    // recursive case ( keep doing this until the length of string is 0.)
    methodName(s.substring(n + 1, s.length()), set);
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[how, return, do, this?, i]
```